Replying to Email in Sale Order Chatter Logs Me Out After "Fetch Now
I'm experiencing a strange issue with my Odoo setup (v17 ). Here's what happens:
I generate a "Send by email" from a Sale Order and send it out.
The recipient replies to the email.
I manually fetch the reply using Fetchmail Server by clicking "Fetch Now".
When I go back to the Sale Order and try to reply in the Chatter, Odoo logs me out immediately.
This behavior happens consistently every time I follow these steps. It seems tied to the manual fetch process, but I’m unsure what’s causing the logout during the Chatter reply. Has anyone else encountered this issue or have any ideas on what might be going wrong?

logs:
2024-12-05 14:48:23,962 3296186 INFO dev-odoo17-11-07-init odoo.addons.base.models.ir_model: Access Denied by ACLs for operation: read, uid: 4, model: sale.order 
2024-12-05 14:48:23,966 3296186 WARNING dev-odoo17-11-07-init odoo.http: You are not allowed to access 'Sales Order' (sale.order) records.

I solved it by removing custom extention mail_tracking. After uninstall problem dissapeared
